# Low level security hash from email address

Tags: php, algorithm, security, hash

I have two servers and one client, this is how the connection works:

Server A = There's many of these, each server for each mobile app.

Server B = There's only one of these. A central server for collecting certain data.

User = There's many of these and these use multiple different mobile apps.
One mobile app only connects to one Server A and the only Server B.

This is how the system works:

1. User starts a Mobile App.
2. The Mobile App asks for registration from the User. The user adds his email, password, name etc. The Mobile App sends the data to Server A.
3. The Server A creates an user account for the User. The Server A returns a low level security hash based of the email.
4. The Mobile App receives the hash and sends it to Server B (among other data such as email, coordinates, Mobile App name, version etc.).
5. Server B receives the email and the hash and uses the same function to recalculate the hash from the email. If the hash calculation ends up being same as the hash sent by the Mobile App, the other data (such as coordinates etc.) are added to the database of Server B.

So the real question is: is there a ready made hashing algorithm for me or should I create one by adding a bunch of md5(), sha1(), strev(), chunking, turning letters to other letters, etc. (this is really simple explanation).

Most optimal ready made algorithm would be one that only needs a salt that's same on both of the servers.

The data is not worth anything to anyone else than me, the only reason we want to put all of this behind a security hash is to prevent troublemakers sending trash data to our database.

PS. I know I could make the Server A send a random hash to Server B and then give the same hash to User and it would be enough but I want to keep the data sending to a minimum since the Server B will be taking a lot of connections each second / minute.

Comment: So basically the *secret* here is the algorithm (not any data), and the proof you want to establish is that the user has talked to Server A before he talks to Server B?

Comment: I assume there's no shared state between Server A and B (access to same database, API or some such)?

Comment: deceze, both correct. thanks once more for the correct answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're basically looking for a *pre-shared secret*, that both servers A and B know, but which is not disclosed elsewhere. You want to be able to give the user a token that he can carry from server A to B, which will proof to server B that the user has talked to server A before; without disclosing the secret shared between server A and B to the user.

The best option here is probably an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac), or message signing. You supply a random secret key to both servers. The message being signed is essentially the email address, so server A "signs" the message with its secret key. Server B repeats the process and compares both signatures.

Note that if anyone intercepts the signature at any point, he can launch replay attacks (simply reusing the signature for arbitrary new requests). *If* the user is talking to server A frequently, you can minimise such replay attacks by including a timestamp in the signature hash which the user is also required to send together with the email address, and limit the validity period of signatures this way.

Comment: +1.  Re "Server B repeats the process and compares both signatures." - seems a slightly better fit to have B validate A's signature using A's public key, rather than B re-applying a shared private key, but all much of a muchness....

Comment: Thank you for the timestamp idea. It's a really good addition to it.